# PHP convert MySQL datetime to Unix Timestamp

Tags: php, timezone, timestamp

I'm confused about timezone differences when converting a MySQL datetime to Unix timestamp. It appears to me that MySQL datetimes (`2011-02-07 09:45:00`) are in the server's local timezone. I want to convert this datetime into a Unix timestamp, which is always in the GMT timezone. To do this conversion, PHP passes the datetime into [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php). The datetime string contains no timezone, so will strtotime assume the argument is local timezone or GMT?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The strtotime function will assume the datetime is in the server's local timezone.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use MySQL's UNIX_TIMESTAMP() function?

Comment: Because the project running on the server, and the sever are in two different timezones. Referring the servers timezone will give wrong data to the site user. I've used php's date_default_timezone_set('XXX'); to change the default timezone for the site.